# Windows has gone missing from the grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I've tried re installing ubuntu 13.10 on my PC by formating it's partition with gparted.

Unfortunately, the Windows 7 option has gone missing from the grub menu.
I tried boot-repair and here is the results- http://paste.ubuntu.com/6708553/

In addintion, sudo update-grub doesn't help nor it prints a line with "window 7".

thank you

Comment: did you installed both ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 on your HDD?

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing two essential Windows boot files, bootmgr & /boot/BCD.Those are what grub2's os-prober looks for. Normally Windows has those in a separate 100MB (hidden) boot partition, but you do not show that partition or missing space for it.

You will have to move boot flag back to sda1 as Windows only repairs the partition with the boot flag. You can use gparted or with your Windows repairCD or flash drive the set active command. And then run Windows repairs to recreate the bootmgr & BCD. If you run auto repairs 3 times, it will also put the Windows boot loader back in and you have to use Boot-Repair or manual install to readd grub to MBR.

Then the sudo update-grub will find Windows. Or Boot-Repair will run it also.

Comment: this has been extreamly helpful, and works perfectly. thanks